# Printing Keyboard Labels

Tags: piano, key, learning-resources

Is there any kind of label sheet size or template that will fit on a piano keyboard?
I want to print from my printer ABC's that will fit on the keyboard.
Thanks!

Comment: Try to avoid this. It's pretty pointless. Your beginner obviously knows the alphabet, otherwise it would be totally useless. Instead, maybe, just put 3 on. A C, F and A will do it. Where's D? right next to C! The point of the keyboard layout is to be easy to find notes. If you do go ahead, are you then going to mark the #/b? Still, it's better than a grand I bought where some helpful had written them on in felt tip - indelible...

Answer (score 2):

Office stationery suppliers sell label sheets in a huge variety of formats, including labels 10mm deep which should be small enough to fit on standard piano keys if you use them "sideways". But even a single sheet would probably label three 88-note keyboards, so you may have to buy far more labels than you actually need.

Google for office suppliers - the SE rules say that we can't give specific product recommendations here.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a template: [Piano Keyboard Diagrams to Print Out](http://www.music-for-music-teachers.com/piano-keyboard.html).

You could also buy the stickers which are widely available. For example, [Keysies Transparent Plastic Removable Piano and Keyboard Note Stickers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00TXC247S)